# css element design excluding inner elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Css

```
.sidebar .nav li:nth-child(1) a {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 24px;
 border: none;
 background: #27AE60;
}
```

Html

```
<li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
 <li id="accordian">
 <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">New Registration</a>
 <ul id="collapseOne" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapse">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i> Resource</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i> Client</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

I want to design first li of parent ul but not the child li

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `.nav` `class` is assigned to `ul` which is directly nested under element having a `class` of `.sidebar` so use the direct child selector here

```
.sidebar > ul.nav > li:first-child a {
   color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/K7xYX/)

> Note: Better use `.sidebar > ul.nav > li:first-child > a` instead of
>   above to be more specific

---

And if you meant every direct `li` which are nested under first level parent `ul` than just get rid of `:first-child` pseudo

```
.sidebar > ul.nav > li > a {
   color: red;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_alien/K7xYX/1/)

Answer (score 1):

From your code `.nav li:nth-child(1)` it looks like what you really want is to style the first li's anchor, but not it's adjacent sibling.

(Although you say

> I want to design first li of parent ul but not the child li

...I think that you meant to say adjacent sibling
)

So actually given that your markup looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li id="accordian"> 
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">New Registration</a>

        <ul id="collapseOne" class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked collapse">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i> Resource</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i> Client</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

.. then the css code you posted actually works.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/fE6ZV/1/)**